# How can I install packages from an SVN server in RStudio?

Tags: r, svn, version-control, rstudio

I would like to check out two folders (downloaded folders) from a svn server, which requires a username and password. 
After giving the username + password + address of the server, as well as the name of folders, how can I do it? Is there any command or packages for this purpose?
I do not want to create a project and use Rstudio as versions controller editor! I just want to download these folders from the server.

Comment: What do you mean by “I do not want to create a project and use Rstudio as versions controller editor”? — what do you wnat to do with RStudio? Would TortoiseSVN not be sufficient for you?

Comment: ok, the problem was not well described by me, sorry. I have been searching more, and guess to know more. I want to use "install.packages " function just to install packages from an svn-server. The question is: how can I do it?

Comment: Perhaps you could edit your question to reflect that. The title could be “How can I install packages from an SVN server in RStudio?”. I’m afraid I don’t know RStudio, so I cannot help further – but a clearer question has a better chance of an answer!

Comment: thanks a lot, I have it done.

Comment: The `devtools` package has an `install_svn` function